# Country of residence? MVV form - The Netherlands

Tags: visas, international-travel, netherlands, embassies

I am a citizen of Mauritius and I currently living in Mauritius. I need to collect my MVV visa at the embassy of the Netherlands in Tanzania and I need to fill the [MVV form](https://www.netherlandsworldwide.nl/binaries/en-nederlandwereldwijd/documenten/publications/2017/09/27/embassy-in-beijing-mvv-issue-form/MVV_issue_form_%28EN%29.pdf) beforehand. However in the [MVV form](https://www.netherlandsworldwide.nl/binaries/en-nederlandwereldwijd/documenten/publications/2017/09/27/embassy-in-beijing-mvv-issue-form/MVV_issue_form_%28EN%29.pdf), I find this part confusing.

[image]

Given my nationality is Mauritian and I will be visiting Tanzania for collecting my MVV visa, does this mean I am residing in another country (Tanzania) other than the country of my current nationality (Mauritius) while collecting/processing my MVV visa?

Kindly advise if anyone had a similar experience. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Visiting is not residing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. Based on what you've written in the question, you are travelling to Tanzania for a short time to collect the visa, but your home address will still be in Mauritius. The question asks where you *reside* - that means it is about where you *live* (not just where you happen to be located at a particular moment), so the answer here is "No".